# Store value of subquery in update for later use

Tags: postgresql, update, subquery

Trying to calculate % change of price. Query below works, but was hoping there was a way that I didn't have to call the same subquery first? I don't think WITH works here unless I'm mistaken.

```
update changes rt1
    set change = coalesce((rt1.price - (SELECT 
        price
      FROM clothing_price
      WHERE changes.id = clothing_price.id AND clothing_price.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
      ORDER BY timestamp ASC
      LIMIT 1) / (SELECT 
        price
      FROM clothing_price
      WHERE changes.id = clothing_price.id AND clothing_price.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
      ORDER BY timestamp ASC
      LIMIT 1)), 0)
where clothing_type = 1;
```

Comment: *I don't think WITH works here unless I'm mistaken.* You're mistaken. Add RETURNING clause into your UPDATE. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32f81e6d06a9d78ca2a58c73c6390a93)

Comment: @akina Thanks, I could be misunderstanding, but I don't think that solves the problem. Main issue with WITH here is that `changes.id` changes for reach record.

Comment: You will obtain an output row for each updated row. With all values which will be specified in RETURNING clause - including those which are not updated and even mentioned in the query (but are present in processed rowset). So simply include `changes.id` into returning list. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c4485a89a65fbb2b9045f3d495a6373) - `test.id` is not used/mentioned in UPDATE but it is successfully returned.

Comment: `Query below works` That's hard to believe. `changes.id` is an invalid reference. Even after changing to  `rt1.id`, it computes `changes.price - 1` if a nonnull `clothing_price.price` is found. Else `change` defaults to `0`. But that can be done  *way* simpler and cheaper. What is the query really supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(After fixing the invalid reference) The query burns down to:

```
UPDATE changes rt1
SET    change = CASE WHEN (
   SELECT cp.price
   FROM   clothing_price cp
   WHERE  cp.id = rt1.id   -- fixed reference!
   AND    cp.timestamp > now() - interval '24 hours'
   ORDER  BY cp.timestamp
   LIMIT  1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rt1.price - 1 END
WHERE  clothing_type = 1;
```

That aside, to "store" the result of a **correlated suquery**, would have to self join to another instance of the updated table `changes` in a `USING` clause. But that seems to be moot now ...

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the speculation, but I'm going to try answering the question using a different strategy.

First, I think the OP was asking about a regular CTE. In PostgreSQL you can use a CTE to feed data to an `UPDATE`. In my answer, I'm going to find the reference price in a CTE (the "stored value", as OP called it in the question title).

Second, the OP's query is likely missing the predicate `AND rt1.id = clothing_price.id` in the final `WHERE`. As written, it will change *every* `change` field with `clothing_type=1`. I assume that each `id` in `changes` was supposed to have its own `change` field filled in.

Applying these assumptions, I wrote the following query, and accompanying [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f614c45c586bf13929b41d4bece394c8) with sample table definitions and data:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.id,t.mints,clothing_price.price 
    FROM (
       SELECT id,
          min(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE timestamp > now() - interval '24 hour') AS mints 
       FROM clothing_price 
       GROUP BY id
    ) t
    LEFT JOIN clothing_price 
    ON (clothing_price.id=t.id and clothing_price.timestamp=t.mints)
)
UPDATE changes SET change = coalesce((changes.price - cte.price)/cte.price,0)
FROM cte
WHERE changes.clothing_type=1 AND changes.id=cte.id;
```

Notes:

- `cte.price` is the reference ("old") price from `clothing_price` and `changes.price` is the incoming ("new") price change.
- `changes.change` will be positive on price increase, negative on price decrease, and zero if prices are all the same, a price is missing, or all prices have expired.
- Used a `LEFT JOIN` so `id`s with expired prices get zeroed by `COALESCE`.